# ! LaTeX Error: File `\unskip ' not found

Tags: tables, graphics, errors

I appear to be having a problem with embedding images in a tabular enviroment. I getting the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `\unskip ' not found.
```

and here is the offending piece of code. The compiler points me to the line beginning with `\multicolumn`

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
      \includegraphics[scale=0.22]{lig_nontp_align.png} &
      \includegraphics[scale=0.22]{transporthist.png} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{\textit{Left:} Non-transport and ligand proteins aligned to the ligand HMM model. \textit{Right:} the three different sub-types of transmembrane proteins aligned to the ligand HMM model. }
\end{figure}
```

I can find problems to do with "\unskip" form googling, but not quite in this capacity. what seems to be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Your example has `\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]` with no file name: is the really in your file? If so, it's a likely culprit as the command will grab whatever follows.

Comment: cheers this was it!

Answer (score 6):

Your example has `\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]` with no file name. The result will be that `\includegraphics` will pick up the next thing it finds as the mandatory argument. Inside a LaTeX tabular cell that will be an `\unskip` (inserted by LaTeX): this needs to be fixed.